# Printing variables side by side in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, list, printing

If I have a listA = ['mark', 'matt', 'peter']
and another listB = [100000, 150, 0]
How would I be able to print this:

```
mark             100000
matt                150
peter                 0
```

Might be a duplicate, but I searched and found no answers.

Comment: Your example values for `listA` and `listB` are not valid Python.

Comment: Edited the question. I just made up something simple to showcase the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the values from you second list to be left aligned you can use

```
A = ['mark', 'matt', 'peter']
B = [100000, 150, 0]

for i, j in zip(A, B):
    print ("%s \t %s" % (i, j))
```

Comment: Even better than the previous answer! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work:

```
for i,j in zip(listA, listB):
    print(i,j)
```

OR in form of pandas dataframe

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'listA':listA ,'listB': listB })
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop with the zip function:

```
for i, j in zip(A, B):
    print (i, j)
```